# How can I install photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: photoshop

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

How I can install Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu using wine or by any other method?

And how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Gimp?  It does everything I ever needed from photoshop, but to me, in a more straightforward (but different) way.  It's always best to use the apps available with the OS you choose.  Ubuntu is not Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to the WINE database, [it gets a good rating.](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607)

So, first things first, install WINE with:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then all you have to do is right click the installer EXE file, and select "open with WINE Windows program loader"

You can install it just as you would on a native Windows box.

Comment: and how i can fix this ??

Comment: @Crazy - Try running `winetricks -q atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko` and reboot. Then run the setup EXE again.

Comment: running `winetricks -q atmlib` fails with following error `Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A04295-D2A8-40D0-A0C5-241BFECD095E/W2KSP4_EN.EXE failed`

Comment: @Ejaz - Then please post as a different question, including that you tried my answer here.

Comment: @Ejaz: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/866877/problem-installing-photoshop-on-16-04-lts/903803#903803

Comment: I would recommend installing it from PlayOnLinux because wine crashes so many times and it is not so stable, actually in my laptop crashed the whole time.

Comment: @DonaldShahini PlayOnLinux is just a wrapper around WINE

Answer (score 3):

You can install it through PlayOnLinux.[PlayOnLinux in ubuntu software center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CjFL.png)
You can download playonlinux from ubuntu software center.

Comment: Needs more specific instructions - this doesn't work as-is