# Problem installing Photoshop on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wine, winetricks, photoshop

I am having a problem installing Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. So far, I have tried following the thread with no success:
[How can I install photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775247/how-i-can-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

The installation of wine does not pose a problem. However, installing the atmlib library with winetricks (winetricks -q atmlib) does not seem to work, as the error message reads:

Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A04295-D2A8-40D0-A0C5-241BFECD095E/W2KSP4_EN.EXE failed

Trying to install CS6 by running the set-up.exe file with wine gives me the error: "Installation failed, installer failed to initialize."

Currently Gimp is not an alternative to Photoshop. Please advise, as using Windows causes severe headaches...

Answer (score 2):

Manually install the latest version of Winetricks:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm -f ./winetricks
sudo apt install wget
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
```

Then run the winetricks command again.

Answer (score 0):

If @QwertyChouskie 's solution, did not work.

The Failed link is on the Wayback Machine. Here's the link https://web.archive.org/web/20150511201233/http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A04295-D2A8-40D0-A0C5-241BFECD095E/W2KSP4_EN.EXE